# Display query string asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, query-string

When I click on below link :

```
<a href="default.aspx/video/?title=I am trying get the string"> hi</a>
```

It displays as :

```
http://example.com/default.aspx/title/?title=I%20am%20trying%20get%20the%20string
```

But I want it to display the link like :

```
http://example.com/default.aspx/title/?title=I_am_trying_get_the_string
```

Comment: `%20` is the url encoded version of space. If you want to replace it with underscore then you'll need to handle that in your code behind.

Comment: @Romoku Hi can you please guide me how to do that.

Comment: `Request.QueryString["title"].Replace("_", " ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use <kbd>[HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)</kbd>

```
 Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["title"]).Replace("_", " ");
```

Comment: I tried it but it is returning the same url with "-" sign.

Comment: I'm sorry I tried selecting both as answered but it is only letting me select one. :(

Comment: Hi, please help, I want something when I click on <a href="default.aspx/video/?title=I am trying get the string"> ---- it should automatically change the to "http://example.com/default.aspx/title/?title=I_am_trying_get_the_string"

Answer (score 0):

You can use as While giving value to query string

```
<a href="default.aspx/video/?title=I_am_trying_get_the_string"> hi</a>
```

to get Desired value in output  use String.Replace() as

```
String value = Request.QueryString["title"].ToString();
String valu = value.Replace("_"," ");
```

for details [refer here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks ------ but only half of the requirement is completed.
I have more then 100's of similar links and I can't change them manually
<a href="default.aspx/video/?title=I am trying get the string">

Comment: where you stuck please tell ?

Comment: than change them dynamically in code behind or you can replace %20 with space while getting the value of query string

Comment: I want something when I click on <a href="default.aspx/video/?title=I am trying get the string"> ---- it should automatically change the to 
"http://example.com/default.aspx/title/?title=I_am_trying_get_the_string"

Comment: you can do this in code behind share your code and I'll tell you

Comment: I have stored similar html tags in database 
div class="img"><a href="rendervideo.aspx/video/?vid=6799194&title=my video title is hello" title="" target="_blank">  width="399" height="300">  </a>      </div"

Comment: if you don't change your input than replace %20 with space instead of _ with space